# Opening up new tab based on ajax response - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, popup, window.open

On clicking a hyperlink,

```
<a href="" ng-click="function(id)">{{id}}</a>
```

I require something to open up in a new tab based upon the response (a flag, lets say - responseFlag) that I get from the ajax call.

Two methods I tried.

Note : Function is dependent on the id, so not using it on page load.

1.

```
$http.get(url).success(function(response) {
        if(response.data.responseFlag==true){
             $window.open("http://www.example.com");
        }
        else{
             //perform something else other that window.open
        }
});
```

The problem here is the 'Popup blockers' in the browsers (Chrome, Mozilla) - that keeps blocking them.

2.

```
var w = $window.open("","_blank");
$http.get(url).success(function(response) {
        if(response.data.responseFlag == true){
              w.location = "http://www.example.com";
        }
        else{
              //perform something else
        }
});
```

Here, if the 'responseFlag = true', it opens up in new tab. But as you might have guessed it, for 'responseFlag = false' too the tab opens up. I can use w.close() in the 'else' perhaps. But I think that's not a solution.

Help me out friends !

Answer (score 0):

In your second example you're openning the new tab before doing the request, so it doesn't matter wich callback gets executed, you'll get a new window openned.
I don't see any reason why $window.open(...) works with your second example but not in the first, maybe is because the "_blank" parameter...

So, can you try this way?

```
$http.get(url).success(function(response) {
        if(response.data.responseFlag == true){
            var w = $window.open("","_blank");
            w.location = "http://www.example.com";
        }
        else{
            //perform something else
        }
});
```

Comment: Well, I tried that. Actually, it seems the tab will only open up in new tab if its from something like direct user activity. Its not in the first case.